# Question about blocks sizes on Tape vs. Tar

Tags: backup, tar, tape

I have an HP LTO-4 drive that I've been using for backups for a while now and everything works very well, but I have a question on how the `Tar` blocking factor works and what is actually written to tape.

When I first starting using the drive I realized that the only way to really restore specific file/directories was to specify the path to restore and the tape, via `Tar`, needed to seek (really search) until it found that record and restored it. I had the idea of writing block locations to the log file with the `-R` switch on the `Tar` command so that I could then issue `mt -f /dev/nst0l seek [block]`and then restore without having to wait so long and wearing the tape and drive. I did my first backup using this and noticed the block numbers were very high, the last block being `block 1393049715` for the last file which is 638.3kB. I'm using a blocking factor of 512; 512x512=262144 (for 256k blocks). I guess this is really the "record length" according the man page. I divided 1393049715 by 512 and got "2720800.22461". When the backup finished I issued `mt -f /dev/nst0l tell` and got `At block 2720804.` So what is that extra ".22461"? How I can calculate the tape-block from the tar-block. Also, if the last file is at block 2720800.22461, and it's size is 638k then the EOD should really be 2720802 not 2720804. Now, I'm guessing this might have something to do with padding or the tape writing "end-of-records" to the tape that Tar doesn't see, but I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: A typical mt program has no `tell` command. What OS are you using?

Comment: it's `mt-st v. 1.3` on Devuan

Comment: A standard `mt` prints the tape position with the `status` command. How did you get the number of blocks written and the blocksize?

Comment: The blocksize is set on the `tar` command i.e `tar -b 512 -cvf /dev/st0` 512 means a blocksize of 256k on the tape. The number of blocks written comes from `mt` via the `tell` command, `status` would probably work too. The `tar` log file also has the block numbers via the `-R` switch but I think it writes the blocking-factor blocks, not the "actual" 256k that are written on the tape, which is what `mt` shows. Thus the number in the log-file is 512-times as large.

Comment: The `gtar -R` output is not useful for your purpose. Even `gtar --totals` does not print what you like to see. I recommend to use `star` as it always prints the number of bytes and the number of records written.

Comment: hmm alright, I might give `star`a try then, thanks.

Comment: `gtar -R` prints the 512 byte based block number for the beginning of the file in the archive. Since you cannot know the exact amount of meta data, it is hard to compute the end of the archive from that.

Comment: BTW: recent star versions are in schilytools.

Comment: yeah I was able to find an RPM and convert it to DEB, but thanks, I'll install the schilytools one. From what I can tell so far it does look like it works. It seems like `star` is missing a `tar -X` equivalent though for an exclude-list.

Comment: Star implements a -X option like UNIX tar since May 2007, see http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html page 47